# Change path in Joomla from localhost

Tags: iis, joomla, localhost

I have joomla install on IIS with a domain that's not registered yet, so we are still using the IP address..

So whenever you go "home" or do some actions in the admin panel it keeps trying to go back to localhost - how do I change it - or do I need to wait for the domain to come on...

The website is here btw - http://12.148.212.142/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it - had to change the settings for "live_site" in configuration.php